# Add a Sprite Kit View to a UIView Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode8

I am making a app that will hopefully have a game in it but in order to do that I need a Sprite Kit View. I was wondering if there was a way to add a Sprite Kit View to a Single View Application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SKView is just a subclass of UIView, so you can add it via code where you want or through the Storyboard.  as of XCode 9 I believe, IB allows you to add an actual SKView where you can set the scene file instead of having to fill the custom class field in.

Comment: the same way you add a regular UIView,  in the view controller, whatever view you want to attach it to, you do `view.addSubview(SKView(...))`

Comment: so just do `view.addSubview(SkView())`

Comment: is there a way to do this in the main.storyboard because the game i am trying to make requires you to make a few nodes in the game scene then link them with the code file

Comment: well you may need to specify parameters and constraints, but you need to learn how to set it up for a regular UIView if you do not already know how to do it

Comment: that is something completely different and outside the realm of this question

Comment: I know how to but in the section to choose what to add to the view there is no SKView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170712/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-jwjbadger).